# scrlttr2: Increasing the headline space on the 2nd page

Tags: spacing, koma-script, scrlttr2

How can I increase the space between the headline and the following text on the second page of the `scrlttr2` document?

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{babel}
\usepackage[]{blindtext}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Bacherstr.\ 16 }

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\setkomavar{nexthead}{%
\vbox to 50pt {\vfil
\hbox to 3cm{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}%
\vfil
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Unternehmen}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}

\blindtext[4]

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the exception of the first page you can set the margins as usual. The first page works with pseudo length. The next pages use the standard settings provided by `typearea`.

To demonstrate this you can load the package `showframe` und manipulate length like `\headsep`. However I recommend the package `geoemtry` to influence the margins.

If I use the following settings in your example

```
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[reset,headheight=2cm]{geometry}
```

I get the following output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case using `geometry` as you suggested changed too much of the other (pseudo) lengths I had already defined. However, setting `\addtolength{\headsep}{1cm}` as per your first suggestion worked brilliantly.